# If checkbox is checked add £1.50 to total if not add nothing

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement

Hi I am trying to make a basic form that adds a value of £1.50 on to total price if check box is checked.  So i have a user input a price (value for a voucher) they can either pick up or get it delivered - delivery is £1.50.

I have a basic knowledge of javascript and found the following code that allows me to add two form fields together -

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function updatesum() {
document.form.sum.value = (document.form.sum1.value -0) + (document.form.sum2.value -0);
}
//--></script>
```

html

```
<form name="form" >
Enter a number:
<input name="sum1" onChange="updatesum()" />
and another number:
<input type="checkbox" name="sum2" onChange="updatesum()" value="1.50" checked> 
Their sum is:
<input name="sum" readonly style="border:0px;">
</form>
```

obviously this works but again obviously the value stays at 1.50 whether the box is checked or not - so i need help with an "if" statement. have searched around but really am quite stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to only add the value if the checkbox is checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesum() {
     var deliveryFee = document.form.sum2.checked ? Number(document.form.sum2.value) : 0;
     document.form.sum.value = (document.form.sum1.value -0) + deliveryFee;
}
</script>
```

You might want to consider using a framework like jQuery to help with this. It will make it easier to write your code and help you keep your code separate from your HTML, improving it's readability and your ability to debug it.

```
<form name="form" >
    Enter a number:
    <input id="voucher" name="cost" />
    and another number:
    <input type="checkbox" id="deliveryFee" name="fee" value="1.50" checked="checked" > 
    Their sum is:
    <input id="total" name="sum" readonly style="border:0px;">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#voucher,#deliveryFee').change( function() {
             var fee = Number( $('#deliveryFee:checked').val() || 0 );
             var cost = Number( $('#voucher').val() );
             $('#total').val( cost + fee );
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: unbelievably fast response, that works perfectly, thank you so much for that, i guess it is quite straight forward once you get your head round it might take me a while though :/

Answer (score 1):

There are some things recommended to do:

Set ids, types and values on the inputs.
Use getElementById('id') to get and set the values.
The most important: parse the inputs as float numbers, then sum and assign.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updatesum(){
    document.getElementById('total').value = 
        parseFloat(document.getElementById('value').value) +
        (document.getElementById('extra').checked?
         parseFloat(document.getElementById('extra').value):0);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" >
Enter a number:
<input name="value" id="value" onChange="javascript:updatesum();" />
add extra 1.5?
<input type="checkbox" name="extra" id="extra" onClick="javascript:updatesum();"
 onChange="javascript:updatesum();" value="1.50" checked=""> 
Their total is:
<input name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly="readonly" style="border:0px;">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

(Sorry about my first edits. I'm a little bit rusty on Javascript. This solution works fine.)

***Note: Add onClick="javascript:updatesum();" to the checkbox input to make it work better in IE.

Comment: You're welcome! Anyway tvanfosson's answer beats mine by miles, and he was so fast I couldn't even see it until I posted mine :)